# How can i get the size of list using retrofit? 'error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1'

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I trying to get the length of my array when parsing json using retrofit, but it return error *android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1*

here is my code.
JobBrowseAdapter.java

```
public class JobBrowseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobBrowseAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Job> jobList;
private Context mContext;
private String id;

public JobBrowseAdapter(Context mContext, List<Job> jobs) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.jobList = jobs;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_project, viewGroup, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    Job job = jobList.get(i);
    myViewHolder.title.setText(job.getTitle());
    myViewHolder.skills.setText("Skills: " + job.getSkills());
    myViewHolder.budget.setText(job.getBudget());
    myViewHolder.bid.setText(job.getBid().size());

    myViewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Job job = jobList.get(i);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, myViewHolder.title.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsProjectActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("idProject", job.getId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Tes nih id nya: " + job.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return jobList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView title;
    private TextView skills;
    private TextView budget;
    private TextView bid;
    private LinearLayout parentLayout;

    private MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleJob);
        skills = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSkillsJob);
        budget = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvBudgetJob);
        bid = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvBid_Project);
        parentLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_browse_project_layout);
    }
}
```

}

i've get the error at **myViewHolder.bid.setText(job.getBid().size());**.
i also tried to use **myViewHolder.bid.setText(jobList().size());** but it still give me same error.
how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `myViewHolder.bid.setText(String.valueOf(job.getBid().size()));`
You are trying to set non String value to `setText()` method so that this is happening

Comment: Welcome, then accept my answer.please

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing

```
myViewHolder.bid.setText(job.getBid().size());
```

do this

```
myViewHolder.bid.setText(String.valueOf(job.getBid().size()));
```

Calling `setText()` with an integer value to a textview will make it find a string with that resource id that is being passed. In your code you are passing the size of the list in `setText()` and it's not able to find the resource string with that id in generated R.string class.